# Setting ViewPager programatically doesn't update TabLayout correctly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

When I setup the `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` and `setCurrentItem()` of `ViewPager` programatically underline color changes correctly but it doesn't happen so with the title color.

I setup my `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` as shown below

```
vpMasterProfile.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.master_profile_tab)));
tlMasterProfile.setupWithViewPager(vpMasterProfile);
```

And on my button click listener I something like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btn_renew){
        vpMasterProfile.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to mention the title color too

Comment: you need to chane title color programmatically, or write that code in `onTabChange()`

Comment: Please show some code as to what you have tried so everyone will be able to guide you better.

Comment: Please check out my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out when I change item of `ViewPager` programmatically it does not sync with `TabLayout`. So I selected the tab programmatically and everything works fine.

```
tlMasterProfile.getTabAt(1).select();
```

Does the trick.